# rsync - include top level file and exclude directories

Tags: rsync

I want to include all top level files (`file1.txt`, `file2`) and only anything under `/top/dir1/`. How can I achieve it?

I have tried the following but they don't work

```
$ tree
.
└── from
    ├── file1.txt
    ├── file2
    └── top
        ├── dir1
        │   └── file3.txt
        └── dir2
            └── file4.txt
```

one attempt, missing top level files

```
$ rsync --dry-run \
>       --include='top/' \
>       --include='top/dir1/' \
>       --include='top/dir1/***' \
>       --exclude='top/*' \
>       --exclude="*" \
>       -av from/* .
building file list ... done
top/
top/dir1/
top/dir1/file3.txt
```

other attempt to include top level files but it's not excluding dir2

```
$ rsync --dry-run \
>       --include="*" \
>       --include='top/' \
>       --include='top/dir1/' \
>       --include='top/dir1/***' \
>       --exclude='top/*' \
>       --exclude="*" \
>       -av from/* .
building file list ... done
file1.txt
file2
top/
top/dir1/
top/dir1/file3.txt
top/dir2/
top/dir2/file4.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use `*` in the source path for rsync, rsync is perfectly capable of finding those entries itself.

By doing that, you've effectively called rsync as

```
rsync --dry-run \
   --include="*" \
   --include='top/' \
   --include='top/dir1/' \
   --include='top/dir1/***' \
   --exclude='top/*' \
   --exclude="*" \
   -av from/file1.txt from/file2 from/top .
```

Include and exclude patterns are relative to the source root; so the `--include 'top/'` etc. patterns will never match.

Do this:

```
rsync --dry-run \
   --include="/*" \
   --include='/top/' \
   --include='/top/dir1/' \
   --include='/top/dir1/***' \
   --exclude='/top/*' \
   --exclude="*" \
   -av from/ .
```